# Button not doing anything when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'd really appreciate a little assistance here. Just a basic form to calculate the costs of a few items in JavaScript. I think I'm missing something critical, but I just can't see it. I'm sure  it is a really simple solution, I've just been looking at it for too long and it is frustrating me.

Right now, my "calculate total" button does not do anything when clicked.

```
<form name="calc" id="books">

    Full Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>



    <br>
    <br>

    <input id="b1" type="checkbox" name="b1" value="book1">book 1   $159.00              Quantity: <input id="bq1" type="number"  size="2" value="1" ><br/>
    <input id="b2" type="checkbox" name="b2" value="book2">book 2   $250.00              Quantity: <input id="bq2" type="number"  size="2" value="1" ><br/>
    <input id="b3" type="checkbox" name="b3" value="book3">book 3   $178.50              Quantity: <input id="bq3" type="number"  size="2" value="1" ><br/>
    <input id="b4" type="checkbox" name="b4" value="book4">book 4   $143.00              Quantity: <input id="bq4" type="number"  size="2" value="1" ><br/>

    <br/>
    <br/>


    <input type="radio" name="campus" value="surface">Surface Mail<br>
    <input type="radio" name="campus" value="air">Air mail

    <br/>
    <br/> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    <input type="button" onclick="calcmyTotal()" value="Calculate myTotal">

</form>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("books").reset();

}


    function calcmyTotal(){ 

        if(document.calc.b1.checked){
            myTotal = document.getElementById("bq1")*159;


        }
        else
            if(document.calc.b2.checked){
                myTotal = document.getElementById("bq2")*250;


            }
            else
                if(document.calc.b3.checked){
                myTotal = document.getElementById("bq3")*178;


                }
                else
                    if(document.calc.b4.checked){
                    myTotal = document.getElementById("bq3")*143;


                    {
                    else{
                        alert("no books have been selected")
                    }


        document.write(myTotal); 


    }
    </script>
```

Comment: You should check your console for errors and always be sure to mention those on your questions and also mention what the actual versus expected behavior is. It's not working is not a useful description

Comment: Actually it should be: myTotal = document.getElementById("bq1").value * 159;

Comment: There are too many errors. You have to debug your own code. For starters, the JavaScript doesn't compile, there'a syntax error. Familiarize yourself with the development tools the browser gives you and debug your code with the help of the error console and the debugger. Once you've done that, if you haven't figured it out, you can ask a question that shows due diligence. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: I've had a look at the links you have provided and I'll keep the former in mind when posting questions in the future. I'm using Mozilla, but the dev tools seem largely interchangeable. As for my specific problem, the console simply says "Syntax Error: syntax error", which unfortunately doesn't really provide any additional help. I must be missing something here.....

Comment: @TheKlax Syntax error is usually an easy one to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is

```
document.getElementById
```

Not

```
getElementById
```

Other errors/problems are

- Syntax Error
- document.write will delete all your HTML from the page
- to get the value of an HTML form input, do `document.getElementById("bq2").value`

Please read my comment on the question about how to ask a question

```
            else
                if(document.calc.b4.checked){
                myTotal = document.getElementById("bq3")*143;


                { // Syntax error: should be }
```

Comment: Ah yes my bad, thanks. That didn't seem to solve it though. The button still doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: And you're still not posting your error message, did you put breakpoints in your code? Check the console

Comment: When you say error message are you referring to what the console says? I have not heard of a break point... I will read up on those now.

Comment: @TheKlax Please do, I've posted links as a comment that explain what a well asked question is and a link to the browser development tools

Comment: `document.getElementById("bq3")*143;`??

Comment: @TJ That's copy pasted from the OP's code, I'm just pointing out what the syntax problem is with their code. I've pointed out the other problems

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in the following code:

```
if(document.calc.b4.checked){
   myTotal = document.getElementById("bq3")*143;
{ // <------------ here
else{
   alert("no books have been selected")
}
```

should be

```
if(document.calc.b4.checked){
   myTotal = document.getElementById("bq3")*143;
}
else{
   alert("no books have been selected")
}
```

Other than that, the `document.getElementById()` method returns a reference to the `HTMLElement`. You should use it's `value` property to access the value in it, like

```
myTotal = document.getElementById("bq3").value *143;
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wxLahmvu/1/)

(*Well working in the sense - working without errors according to your current logic - onclick of `calculate total` button, `document.write` re-writes the page with the value in `myTotal`*)